# Access 2010: Union with nested selection

Tags: sql, select, union, ms-access-2010

I have have this query that i want to execute.

```
 SELECT warehouse.expiry_date, pharmacy.expiry_date,
   drugs.active_substance, 
   drugs.strength, 
   drugs.strength_type, 
   drugs.dosage_form,  
   drugs.minimum_quantity,
   SUM(QTY-QTYQ) as QTYU
 FROM
 (SELECT warehouse.expiry_date, 
   drugs.active_substance, 
   drugs.strength, 
   drugs.strength_type, 
   drugs.dosage_form,  
   drugs.minimum_quantity,
   SUM(warehouse.in_quant)-  SUM(warehouse.out_quant) as QTY
 FROM drugs INNER JOIN warehouse ON drugs.ID = warehouse.drug_id  
 GROUP BY warehouse.expiry_date,
   drugs.active_substance, 
   drugs.strength, 
   drugs.strength_type, 
   drugs.dosage_form, 
   drugs.minimum_quantity

 UNION ALL

 SELECT pharmacy.expiry_date, 
   drugs.active_substance, 
   drugs.strength, 
   drugs.strength_type, 
   drugs.dosage_form,  
   drugs.minimum_quantity,
   SUM(pharmacy.out_quant)-  SUM(pharmacy.out_quant) as QTYQ
 FROM drugs INNER JOIN pharmacy ON drugs.ID = pharmacy.drug_id  
 GROUP BY pharmacy.expiry_date,
   drugs.active_substance, 
   drugs.strength, 
   drugs.strength_type, 
   drugs.dosage_form, 
   drugs.minimum_quantity)
 GROUP BY 
 warehouse.expiry_date,
   drugs.active_substance, 
   drugs.strength, 
   drugs.strength_type, 
   drugs.dosage_form, 
   drugs.minimum_quantity,
  pharmacy.expiry_date;
```

When i try to execute it the program want to enter parameter value for pharmacy.expiry_date and QTYQ. But these values are in my nested selection.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT InWarehouse.expiry_date, 
        drugs.active_substance,
        drugs.strength,
        drugs.strength_type,
        drugs.dosage_form,
        drugs.minimum_quantity,
        COALESCE(SUM(InWarehouse.quantity), 0) 
           - COALESCE(SUM(InPharmacy.quantity), 0) as quant
 FROM drugs 
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT drug_id, expiry_date, SUM(in_quant - out_quant) as quantity
            FROM Warehouse
            GROUP BY drug_id, expiry_date) as InWarehouse
 ON InWarehouse.drug_id = drugs.id
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT drug_id, expiry_date, SUM(in_quant - out_quant) as quantity
            FROM Pharmacy
            GROUP BY drug_id, expiry_date) as InPharmacy
 ON InPharmacy.drug_id = drugs.id
 AND InPharmacy.expiry_date = InWarehouse.expiry_date
 GROUP BY InWarehouse.expiry_date, 
          drugs.active_substance,
          drugs.strength,
          drugs.strength_type,
          drugs.dosage_form,
          drugs.minimum_quantity
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't appear to have any host variables, my telepathy is telling me this is related to the syntax errors you have in your statement.  Specifically, `QTYQ` does not appear to exist (the column by that name is masked by the column `QTY` in the preceeding part of the `UNION ALL`), and `pharmacy.expiry_date` is at the wrong location in the `GROUP BY`, given the order of your selection columns.  The final subtraction statement (`SUM(QTY - QTYQ)`) is attempting to subtract two different *rows*, but you don't give it any correllation (you want columns, really).  There's also a typo that would give you incorrect results (`SUM(pharmacy.out_quant) - SUM(pharmacy.out_quant)` should return 0, probably not what you want.  The optimizer may not even bother calling the function, if it's smart enough).

Here's your query, re-written to a better form, which I think will do you in better stead.  Please note that this isn't tested, and **you** are responsible for verifying that it returns correct results for your needs.  You will also require a [Calendar file](http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html), which you should probably have regardless.

```
SELECT Calendar.date, 
       Drugs.active_substance,
       Drugs.strength,
       Drugs.strength_type,
       Drugs.dosage_form,
       Drugs.minimum_quantity,
       COALESCE(SUM(InWarehouse.quantity), 0) 
          - COALESCE(SUM(InPharmacy.quantity), 0) as quant
FROM Drugs 
CROSS JOIN Calendar
LEFT JOIN (SELECT drug_id, expiry_date, SUM(in_quant - out_quant) as quantity
           FROM Warehouse
           GROUP BY drug_id, expiry_date) as InWarehouse
ON InWarehouse.drug_id = Drugs.id
AND InWarehouse.expiry_date = Calendar.date
LEFT JOIN (SELECT drug_id, expiry_date, SUM(in_quant - out_quant) as quantity
           FROM Pharmacy
           GROUP BY drug_id, expiry_date) as InPharmacy
ON InPharmacy.drug_id = Drugs.id
AND InPharmacy.expiry_date = Calendar.date
GROUP BY Calendar.date, 
         Drugs.active_substance,
         Drugs.strength,
         Drugs.strength_type,
         Drugs.dosage_form,
         Drugs.minimum_quantity
```

Comment: In case i don't have a Calendar, how can I use the aforementioned sql code?

Comment: I tried it without the calendar but for the  COALESCE(SUM(InWarehouse.quantity), 0) 
          - COALESCE(SUM(InPharmacy.quantity), 0) I get wrong values.

Comment: Wrong values how?  I performed mu best guess as to what you were going for, based on the statement you showed, but you didn't necessarily give enough to make it correct - a set of example data and desired output would be helpful here.  As for the `Calendar` stuff - I was assuming you wanted all dates worth of data, regardless of which rows existed; this would require some way to get all the dates.  If you don't have the relevant file (or can't create one), you need some way to generate it on the fly.  In other systems, this is done with a recursive CTEs, does Access support them?

Comment: That was very helpful! I did it without the calendar.

Comment: @Zinon - If you figured it out on your own, could you please post it as a seperate answer, so that future questioners may benefit?